# Installation Recaptcha fails on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: installation, magento2.3.3, recaptcha

I'm trying to install Recaptcha on Magento 2.3.3. with the following command in SSH `composer require msp/recaptcha`

but it stated the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires msp/recaptcha 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by msp/recaptcha[2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires msp/recaptcha 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by msp/recaptcha[2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires msp/recaptcha 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by msp/recaptcha[2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.3].>
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Can somebody helpm or hint me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install it. Recaptcha extension is bundled and installed with Magento Open Source and Magento Commerce 2.1.18 and 2.2.9 and later.

It seems you are using 2.1.3, and you **must** upgrade your magento ASAP due to dozens of security issues.

If you want to give it a try anyway, try with `--ignore-platform-reqs` at the end of your command.